# calculate n number of possibilities with array values

Tags: java, android, data-structures

I have three arrays

```
A[]={"a","b"},B[]={"c","d"},C[]={"e","f"}.

Output={"ace"},{"acf"},{"ade"},{"adf"},{"bce"},{"bcf"},{"bde"},{"bdf"}
```

By using these three arrays i have to calculate the possibilities.
Similarly i want to calculate the possibilities for n number of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Use this way

```
 for (int i = 0; i <A.length ; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <B.length ; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k <C.length ; k++) {
              Log.e("output",A[i]+B[j]+C[k]);

            }

        }
    }
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

Can be solved by backtracking, please find the code below.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class NumberOfPossibilities {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    char[] A = {'a', 'b'};
    char[] B = {'c', 'd'};
    char[] C = {'e', 'f'};

    List<char[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(A);
    list.add(B);
    list.add(C);

    dfs(list, result, builder, 0);

    for (String str : result)
        System.out.println(str);
}

public static void dfs(List<char[]> list, List<String> result, StringBuilder builder, int index) {

    if (builder.length() == list.size()) {
        result.add(builder.toString());
        return;
    }

    for (char ch : list.get(index)) {
        builder.append(ch);
        dfs(list, result, builder, index + 1);
        builder.setLength(builder.length() - 1);
    }
}
```

}